# php remote download multi images and crop

Tags: php

i'm beginner in php, i want to download some images And i want to cut it before saving from the bottom of the photo, Below is a code I write and works fine. There is only one problem. I think because the file is stored in the same name. Only one photo is saved, How to use the **php hexdec or md5** function for each name-separated photo

```
$array[] = "http://up.abdolahzadeh.ir/view/2142160/5820073910.jpg";
$array[] = "http://up.abdolahzadeh.ir/view/2142169/4899388870.jpg";

foreach($array as $value) {

$im = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($value));
$width = imagesx($im);
$height = imagesy($im);
$newwidth = $width;
$newheight = $height-20;
$offset_x = 0;
$offset_y = 0;
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopy($thumb, $im, 0, 0, $offset_x, $offset_x, $newwidth, $height);
imagejpeg($thumb,'myChosenName.jpg'); //save image as jpg
imagedestroy($thumb);
imagedestroy($im);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change the line

```
imagejpeg($thumb,'myChosenName.jpg');
```

For

```
imagejpeg($thumb, rand() '.jpg');
```

Comment: thank you i created a random number Generator function And the problem was solved